EF Core: Global Query Filter leads to table creation for base type
Let's assume that I have following entities:
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

And model configuration:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassOne>().ToTable("ChildsOne");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassTwo>().ToTable("ChildsTwo");
}

The migrations generated from the entities and configuration above creates only two tables, omitting the table for the base type.
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ChildsOne",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            PropertyOne = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
            BaseProperty = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ChildsOne", x => x.Id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ChildsTwo",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            PropertyTwo = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
            BaseProperty = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ChildsTwo", x => x.Id);
        });
}

However, after Global Query Filter addition:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Global Query Filter
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Id == x.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassOne>().ToTable("ChildsOne");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassTwo>().ToTable("ChildsTwo");
}

The migration generated after this addition creates a table for the base type.
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    // HERE: Table for the base class is being created
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "BaseClass",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            BaseProperty = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_BaseClass", x => x.Id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ChildsOne",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            PropertyOne = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ChildsOne", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ChildsOne_BaseClass_Id",
                column: x => x.Id,
                principalTable: "BaseClass",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ChildsTwo",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
            PropertyTwo = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ChildsTwo", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ChildsTwo_BaseClass_Id",
                column: x => x.Id,
                principalTable: "BaseClass",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });
}

Is it possible to apply a Global Query Filter without a need to create a table for the base type?

It's because modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>() registers BaseClass as an entity -  see Including types in the model. You need different approach for applying global query filter for all derived entities from a base class.

Use this function to apply global filters ApplyQueryFilter - modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilter<BaseClass>(x => x.Id == x.Id); It will register filters individually for each class without registering BaseClass as class which needs mapping to database.

You can specify it on every table instead:
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassOne>()
    .ToTable("ChildsOne")
    .HasQueryFilter(x => x.Id == x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassTwo>()
    .ToTable("ChildsTwo")
    .HasQueryFilter(x => x.Id == x.Id);

You can automate this with some reflection and expression trees - see the Using Global Query Filters for all entities.
Alternatively you can try setting up the Table-per-concrete-type configuration:
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>()
    .UseTpcMappingStrategy()
    .HasQueryFilter(x => x.Id == x.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassOne>().ToTable("ChildsOne");
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClassTwo>().ToTable("ChildsTwo");


The limitation of the Global Query Filter says that it can only be applied to the root entity type. So can I apply it for each table?

@Qwertyluk the setup worked just fine for me (though I've used more "meaningful" filter - x => x.Id == 1)

@Qwertyluk actually both setups worked.

@Qwertyluk also without seeing exposed sets it is hard to tell do you actually have an inheritance hierarchy or not. Just inheriting from a common base class does not mean that you have it from EF Core point of view. I.e. in my context I had only DbSet<ChildClassOne> and DbSet<ChildClassTwo> exposed so the first setup has not resulted in inheritance hierarchy present from EF Core point of view (and second one did)

The setup also worked for me, but I'm still confused by the limitation of the Global Query Filter mentioned in the documentation

@Qwertyluk was glad to help! If answer works for you feel free to accept and upvote it. "I'm still confused by the limitation" - have not tested it but (as I wrote) my guess is that it applies to inheritance hierarchies in database (which the first setup does not result in). See the last linked document in the answer.

I was so confused by this limitation that I decided to ask another question on Stack Overflow. The answer is that if I don't register the base type of my entity in the ORM, the base type is not treated as the root entity type. It means that as long as I don't have modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>(), it should work.

@Qwertyluk yes, that is exactly what I have meant.
